# How to change the zone file records for .io domain registered at nic.io?

Tags: dns, domain-registration

I just registered a `.io` domain at `nic.io` and I want to make changes to the zone file to integrate it with Google Apps. I couldn't find an interface to change CNAME / MX records.

Has anybody been able to figure out how to do this?

Comment: I'm in the same point -- I have a .io domain, but I can't find a way to edit MX records, I can only have xxx@xxx.io forward to another email...

Comment: @shortstuffsushi exactly. I actually wound up just transfering my domain ownership from nic.io to gandi.net which provides features to edit all records including CNAME/ MX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly an 'answer' per se, but since my domain has it's nameservers on Digital Ocean, I was able to set the MX records on there.

Since nic.io doesn't provide you the ability to set MX records, you'll likely have to either use a different registrar (as you seem to have done), or use another service's nameservers that allow you to reconfigure DNS items including MX records.